# Arithmetic error with count_if()

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda

i was experimenting with algorithm and lambdas when i came across this weird bug:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<int> vec(10);
    int OddCount;

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; ++i)
    {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }

    OddCount = count_if(vec.begin(),vec.end(),[](int v){return v%2 == 0;});

    cout<<OddCount<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

i am aware that the vector vec, contains the values 1 - 10, when i check for odd numbers using the count_if algorithm, it returns the expected number which is 5(1,3,5,7,9) but when i check for even numbers i get the result = 15, which is weird. what's going on?

Comment: v%2 == 0 means v will be even, so you're actually counting even numbers, not odd.

Comment: Ah right sorry about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here:

```
vector<int> vec(10);
```

You first create a vector of size `10` with value-initialized elements, so all having value `0` (this is probably the part you were misunderstanding).

Then, here:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; ++i)
{
    vec.push_back(i);
}
```

You **add** further 10 elements ranging from 1 to 10, which means you are adding exaclty 5 even elements. Therefore, the number of even elements is 15, and the output is correct.

Also notice, that your predicate is indeed selecting the *even* numbers, not the odd numbers (which is what seems to be your intention):

```
[](int v){return v%2 == 0;}
//                   ^^^^
//                   This makes your predicate select EVEN numbers!
```

You should then rewrite it as (for instance):

```
[](int v){return v%2 != 0;}
//                   ^^^^
//                   This makes your predicat select ODD numbers
```

---

As a side note, in C++11 you could use the new [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) algorithm do what I guess you originally meant to do:

```
#include <algorithm> // <== NECESSARY FOR std::iota

// ...

iota(begin(vec), end(vec), 1);
```

Which is the same as (in C++03):

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; ++i)
{
    vec[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: There can be a reason to preallocate a vector before inserting the items (though not really for 10 items). If you want to get all the memory allocation out of the way early, reserving memory for a huge vector (so you don't get lots of reallocations) but not putting items in that memory, use the [`vector::reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) method.

Comment: @Steve314: Right, but that's not what the constructor accepting an `std::size_t` does (although that's perhaps what the OP expected)

Comment: Thanks, it was the pre allocation that made the error, (I thought push_back() would just put values in and nothing else)

Comment: @MauriceRodriguez: All right, glad I could help ;)